# Redux dispatching actions in a specific order

Tags: reactjs, redux

previously i asked a question on how to force a dispatch to complete before doing an action , however i did not really come to a resolution to my problem. [redux problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103352/how-to-force-redux-dispatch-to-finish-first-before-doing-a-next-action) .

It would seem that wrapping dispatch in a promise does nothing as the promise would be resolved once the dispatch is made , not necessarily reduced as mentioned by in one of the comments .

Here is my code:

```
export const selectObjectTransition = (transition) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: IS_DONE,
      isDone: false
      })
    dispatch(loadObjectTransitionApprovals(transition.id));  
    dispatch(loadObjectTransitionHooks(transition.id));  
    dispatch({
      type: SELECT_TRANSITION,
      selected_transition: transition,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: IS_DONE,
      isDone: true
      })
    } 
}
```

basically , what i wish to achieve is that the dispatch be carried out and completed in the following order (top to bottm) . Right now , it would occasionally break and complete the dispatch in different orders , resulting in an error at my front end .

My redux dev tool :

```
IS_DONE -> SELECT_TRANSITION -> IS_DONE -> ......
```

Whereas the 2nd `IS_DONE` action is supposed to be carried out the last

Comment: dont call actionsall at the same time hoping they would all get dispatched at once, instead use ```componentDidUpdate(prevProps)``` to check if action is dispatched and reducer is updated, then send the second action and then do the same, and then send the third action.

Comment: is there a better way of doing this? Because sometimes i would expect to receive a null or empty results , so its not reliable to check if i received data , but instead checking if the action itself is completed

Comment: Not that I can think of, I would create another field in my reducer, like ```dataFecthing```, call it every time you call an action, in the beginning ```dataFetching:true```  and after you receive a response ```false```, it should solve your problem in ```componentDidUpdate```, cause it will get called and update the props at all times.

Answer (score 0):

Besides my comments above, you can also try this

```
export const toDispatch = () =>{
  return dispatch =>{
    axios.get(url).then(()=>{
     dispatch(functionToDispatch())
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) it will help you write a generator function that will help you to make those asynchronous flows easy to read, write, and test.

here is an example :

```js
function* fetchUser(action) {
   try {
      //you can call your here your actions that you want to dispatch
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "USER_FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}
function* mySaga() {
  yield takeEvery("USER_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them in a try-catch block and call the action dispatch as async for each of your dispatch calls - generally it looks like:

```
export const actionName = ({VariablesToPassToTheAction}) => async(dispatch) => {

};
```

Try adapting this mechanism for all your actions that involve api calls. Finally wrap your stuff inside try-catch blocks. If an error occurs, subsequent dispatches fail and the catch block is called, otherwise they are executed in order:

```
export const selectObjectTransition = (transition) => async(dispatch) => {
    try{
dispatch({
      type: IS_DONE,
      isDone: false
      })
    dispatch(loadObjectTransitionApprovals(transition.id));  
    dispatch(loadObjectTransitionHooks(transition.id));  
    dispatch({
      type: SELECT_TRANSITION,
      selected_transition: transition,
    });
    dispatch({
      type: IS_DONE,
      isDone: true
      })
    }

  catch(err){
    //control shifts here if any dispatch fails. Don't forget to handle the error
    }
}
```